# How to Fire Event (Interaction Event) without data values?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

How to fire event i:e Interaction Event after adding multiple rows to data extension linked with journey builder using REST API ?

PS:

1. I know you can fire the event sending all required field values to event using REST but I want to fire event without values so all new rows added previously to data extension added to journey builder when you fire the event.
2. Also you can schedule an automation which can execute / Fire Event or you can use triggered automation putting a file at your FTP location.

So please if any one can help

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is very straightforward. If you have an existing Contact Record in your Contact Model, then you can fire an Event for that Contact (using the REST API) with an empty data object. Here are the steps that you need to follow.

### 1. Create Event Source DE

You need to create a "dummy" event source DE. Create a Sendable Data Extension (Event Source DE's need to be sendable) and just include a single field (which can be named anything you like) and make it **nullable**. Refer to screenshot below.

[image: Create new Data Extension]

### 2. Create Interaction

Create a new Journey Builder Interaction using the Event Source DE you created earlier. Note that your Event Source DE **does not** need to be added to your Contact Model (in Data Designer). Add Activities to the Interaction as required.

### 3. Publish Interaction

Click **Activate** to publish your Interaction.

> **Note:** when publishing an Interaction, all Activities in your Interaction will be validated. If you included Send Email Activities, then these will be validated against the Event Source DE, so if you are using AMPscript `%%personalization%%` strings in your email, you will need to replace these with `Lookup()` functions, as this data won't be available in your Event Source DE.

### 4. Fire Event

Fire the Event using the Events method with an empty `data` object. Set the value of `ContactKey` to the Contact that you want to inject into the Interaction and `eventDefinitionKey` as the value of the Event Definition Key (accessible from the Entry Sources page in Journey Builder). Refer to sample request payload below.

```json
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/events
Authorization Bearer {{accessToken}}
Content-Type application/json

{
   "contactKey":"aafcac6f-9e0a-379c-5b9c-1cd27e3166ef",
   "eventDefinitionKey":"ContactEvent-44f3393c-2588-3683-620d-73fe7ce5de10",
   "EstablishContactKey": false,
   "data":{}
}
```

When you do this, the Contact will be injected into the Journey.

Comment: Thanks Eliot for your detailed information, but I think you missed the point. we need to send the data as well to be included in the email.

Comment: This way we cannot inject any contact which we added into data extension.

Comment: Sorry, your title 'without data values' confused me. Simply include the name/value pairs in your data object (matching the field names in the Event Source DE). Note that Send Email Activities are Triggered Emails, so you will need to add Profile Attributes for the Subscriber. I've [documented this here](https://code.exacttarget.com/blog/salesforce-marketing-cloud-new-releases-what-they-mean-for-developers/#personalizationstringsinemailnov2014release). Once you've done this, any `%%personalization%%` strings in your email will be populated from the data in your Event Source DE.

Comment: Is there any ways we can send multiple events in one go. I mean multiple rows in data attribute